# How does Express's res.end() work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The [docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.end) don't really say much.

> Ends the response process. Inherited from Node's http.ServerResponse.
>
> Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as res.send() and res.json().

```
res.end();
res.status(404).end();
```

1. So is anything sent to the client? I sense that the status line and headers are sent, but no body is sent. Why else would they give the example of `res.status(404).end()`.
2. If you provide an argument to `res.end()`, will it send the argument you provided along in the response body like Node's [response.end()](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a information back, you must end the stream of information. You do this by calling `end()`. Sending the status code `404` can still be followed by content, such as a custom `404` page, rather than the browser showing you the default `This page can not be found` ([Old, but an example of Chrome's built-in 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scpH5.jpg)). If you do not end the request, the browser will keep waiting for the end of the stream and report a timeout after a certain amount of time.

`res.send()` automatically closes the request for you, so that you don't have to call `end()` manually.

Comment: Ah ok - so it ends the TCP connection between the client and server? Is that what you mean by stream?

Comment: Data is sent over TCP in parts, it's not guaranteed to arrive in one time. It's a stream, so that means data goes in on one side and comes out on the other. As long as the stream is open, data can be expected, when the stream is closed, no data will be sent anymore. See it as a small creek. If you have a creek with flowing water and little boats blocked by a dam, the boats will never start moving until you open the dam. Once you close the dam (`end()`), boats will no longer move. If there is no water arriving at the other end of the creek, you won't expect boats, because they can't flow.

Comment: Thank you! I'm curious - how did you learn about that? A class? Book? Tutorial? I'm learning to code and I'm just curious how others do it.

Comment: Most of it is self study, but recently got a networking course at my game development study so it cleared some things up a bit more, mainly security (SSL)

Comment: Note that `ServerResponse#end()` doesn't necessarily close the TCP connection.  If HTTP keep-alives are enabled, [the TCP connection is not closed; it may be reused for additional requests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28310456/201952).

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the [source](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/4.11.2/lib/response.js), we see that express doesn't actually provide a `end()` method.  That's what the docs’ “Inherited from Node's http.ServerResponse” tells you – express doesn't provide this method; [node core's http module does](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.36/lib/http.js#L914-1008).

So what does http's `end()` do?

1. If HTTP response headers have not yet been sent, they are written to the response stream.
2. If `end()` is called with a `data` argument, the data is passed to `write()`.
3. If it is necessary to send [trailers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1), those are written to the response stream.
4. Emits the `finish` event on the response object, which:

   - If the connection uses [keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), node starts processing the next HTTP request.
   - Otherwise, the underlying TCP socket is closed.

So to answer your questions:

1. Is anything sent to the client?  It depends.  Calling `end()` will never cause additional payload (entity-body) data to be sent, but depending on what you've done with the response prior to calling `end()`, more bytes *may* be written to the underlying socket by node on your behalf.

   Your intuition is correct; `res.status(404).end()` will cause the server to respond with HTTP 404 headers and a `Content-Length` of zero (totally empty body).
2. Yes, data passed to `end()` is written to the response stream because the `end()` method **is** node's.  It's important to remember that the request and response objects that express gives you are just regular [`http.IncomingMessage`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) and [`http.ServerResponse`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) objects that are augmented with some [additional](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/4.11.2/lib/request.js) [functionality](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/4.11.2/lib/response.js) by express in the form of extra methods.  All of the methods provided by node core are still available.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized when ending a stream with `res.end( )` without passing any data doesn't end the stream as expected. This happens in cases where you render a file and send data along with it, you have to explicitly call `res.end( JSON.stringify( {data: data} ) )`. I don't know if anyone else has encountered a similar situation. Didn't find it in the docs and it took me some time to figure out why rendering took so long with no success.